# Find the cumulant generating function $K(t)=\log(M(t))$ for a random variable in the exponential family

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the exponential family written as $$f(y;\theta;\phi)=\exp\left(\frac{\theta y - b(\theta)}{a(\phi)}+c(y, \phi)\right).$$ I don't know how to find the moment generating function $$M(t)=E(\exp(Y_t)).$$ I have been give that the cumulant function $$K(t)=\frac{b(\theta+a(\phi)t)-b(\theta)}{a(\phi)}$$ but I have no idea how the answer was obtained. Is this a standard result? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $\theta, \phi, a, b, $ and $c$?

Comment: Simplifying somewhat the notations, as a PDF, each $f_\theta$ integrates to $1$ hence $$\int e^{a^{-1}\theta y+c(y)}dy=e^{a^{-1}b(\theta)}$$ hence (correcting a typo), using the PDF at parameter $\theta+at$, $$M(t)=E(e^{tY})=\int e^{ty}f_\theta(y)dy=e^{-a^{-1}b(\theta)}\int e^{a^{-1}(at+\theta) y+c(y)}dy=e^{-a^{-1}b(\theta)}e^{a^{-1}b(at+\theta)}$$ as desired.